# How to debug app on two devices/emulators?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to debug communication between two Android apps. I have Android Studio 3.0.1.
I don't understand how to start up two instances of the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, DipendraSharma's answer is wrong.

You can't watch the logcat for two devices at the exact same time, since you can't have two active instances of logcat at once (there is a post about this somewhere, but I can't find it). However, you can launch the app on as many devices as you have available at once, and change between the devices tab in the logcat window. Just like you'd select multiple items in i.e. a directory, you pick the devices you want. Press CTRL (or the equivalent on a different keyboard) and press the devices you want. Example:

[image: Screenshot showing two devices highlighted]

Then, like normal, press launch and after a short while of compiling and launching, it'll show up on both (or however many devices you picked). There is going to be a delay between the nth and the n+1th device in terms of launch.

Now, open logcat. You'll see this:

[image: screenshot from the logcat menu highlighting a dropdown with a device name in it]

The dropdown with the device allows you to change the current device you're debugging and can see log info about. Change this as you need.

---

So yes, you can debug on multiple devices at once. This also applies to emulators. And they mix, so if you want to test on two emulators and two real devices, simply pick the ones you want and it'll launch on all the devices.

For emulators, you can debug as many at once as your computer allows you. For real devices, you can debug as many as you have USB ports for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is really interesting. When I arrive at home I will try your advice.

Comment: I was saying to log two differents apps not two different devices.

Comment: @Zoe I tried your advice and I couldn't select several devices. I pressed CTRL, ALT and SHIFT but the Studio allow to choise only one device or emulator. What's wrong? Perhaps there are some settings.

Comment: Press just control or shift. Pressing all at once will not work, and you have to hold it in when you select

Comment: @Zoe, does it like files in Explorer? It didn't work in my case. :(

Comment: @Zoe I understood my mistake. I selected Debug. When I selected Run the Studio allow to choose a several devices/emulators.

Comment: @Dipendra Sharma, Sorry my English.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug communication between two apps by:

```
1- Opening both Android Studio projects of course in two different windows.
2- Running each app on a separate device/emulator.
3- Attaching the debugger from each project to the relative app instance.
4- Set up break-points and debug!
```